# ECS Container exit reason and exit code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I have developed a lambda which triggers when the ECS Container exits due to some issue.
The triggers and send an alert message based on Event which it got.

For some reason when the exit code is 0 or 1, it doesn't return any reason.

So i just ignored this event and focused on events which has reason so that devops team can work propely with actual reason and it will save there time.

But recently I get event with exit code 2, and I want to know how these exit code are generated and in which kind of exit codes will return the exit reason and it will be important for the devops teams.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to act on specific exit codes and use [`DescribeTasks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTasks.html) and/or [`GetLogEvents`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html) API to get more information.

[The most common exit codes](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-task-stopped):

- 0 – Entrypoint, success, or CMD is completing its execution and thus the container is stopped.
- 1 – Refers to application error. For more information, review application logs.
- 137 – Occurs when the Task was force exit ( SIGKILL) for the container:
  Failing to respond to a SIGTERM within a default 30-second period after which the SIGKILL value is sent and containers are forcibly stopped. The default 30-second period can be configured on the ECS container agent with ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT parameter.
  This could also occur in an Out-of-Memory (OOM) situation. Review your CloudWatch metrics to verify if OOM occurred.
- 139 – Occurs when a segmentation fault is experienced. Likely, the application tried to access a memory region which it not available, or there is an unset or invalid environment variable.
- 255 – Occurs when the ENTRYPOINT CMD command in your container failed due to an error. Review your CloudWatch Logs to confirm this.

Comment: The question is specifically about exit code `2`. Your answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @MarkB No, the question is about "how these exit code are generated and in which kind of exit codes will return the exit reason". I don't have an exhaustive list of all exit codes but I thought that the list that exists together with information on how to collect more information about errors could be helpful to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank @duckoak The list is helpful, Yet I am still confuse regarding Exit code 2. Which was retuned without any reason. If you have any idea regarding exit code 2 then please mention it.